# Problema na edição dos dados - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma grid com os dados e também possui um botão de editar.

Problema:
Quando clico em alterar e começo a modificar os dados, lá na grid os dados estão sendo mudados também, mesmo sem ter salvado.

Minha função que carrega os dados é essa:

```
 /* Função que carrega na grid, TODOS os pacientes cadastrados */
 $scope.loadPacientes = function(){
    OdontoService.load('rest/paciente/loadPacientes').then(function (data) { 
        $scope.pacientes = data.data;

        /* For para formatar a data no formato certo */
        for(var x = 0; x < $scope.pacientes.length; x++){
            $scope.pacientes[x].dataNascimento = new Date($scope.pacientes[x].dataNascimento);
        }

    },function (error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Queria que os dados só fossem alterados na grid, quando eu salvasse e não quando eu estou editando ainda.

Comment: Provavelmente isso acontece porque os dados na grid estão associados ao mesmo "model" tanto na edição quanto no grid, o que pode fazer é usar um modelo auxiliar somente para edição e atribuir o valor somente ao confirmar a edição.

Comment: @LucasCosta e é uma boa prática fazer isso?

Comment: sim @GuilhermeNass, se você quer esse comportamento não vejo outra alternativa, porque se uma variavel de escopo estiver sendo usada em *n* lugares, quando ela for alterada todos os lugares que estão exibindo ela serão alterados também, culpa do data binding :p

Comment: @LucasCosta Entendi cara, hehe. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Coloca teu comentário como resposta, para eu selecionar como resolvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a variável de escopo estiver sendo usada em mais de um lugar, caso modificada, mostrará a alteração onde ela estiver sendo aplicada na *view*, isso devido ao [data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) que automaticamente sincroniza os dados entre o modelo e a *view*.

Para previnir essa situação no seu cenário, você pode criar um variável de escopo auxiliar e associar a edição.